# Regex to stop parsing after semicolon is encountered

Tags: c#, regex

I am using this regex to parse URL from a semicolon separated string.

```
\b(?:https?:|http?:|www\.)\S+\b
```

It is working fine if my input text is in these formats:

```
    "Google;\"https://google.com\""
//output - https://google.com
    "Yahoo;\"www.yahoo.com\""
//output - www.yahoo.com
```

but in this case it gives incorrect string

```
"https://google.com;\"https://google.com\"" 
//output - https://google.com;\"https://google.com
```

how can I stop the parsing when I encounter the ';' ?

Comment: You can do a substring on the sttring first to parse out the string up to the first semi colin, then use your regex on that part of the string

Comment: Yes, split the string on the `;`, then run the regex on each substring as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your examples, I would just match any URL between quotation marks. Something like this:

```
(?<=")(?:https?:|www\.)[^"]*
```

[You can try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/HVj9n1/3)

Or as others have said, split the input string by the semicolon character using `string.Split`, and check each string sequentially for your desired match.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally just modify the regex to look specifically for URLs and add some conditionals to the https:// protocols and www quantifier. Using \S+ can be kind of iffy because it will grab every non whitespace character, in which in a URL, it's limited on the characters you can use.

Something like this should work great for your particular needs.

```
(https?:\/{2})?([w]{3}.)?\w+\.[a-zA-Z]+
```

This sets up a conditional on the `http` (`s` also optional) protocol which would then be immediately be followed by the `://`. Then, it will grab all letters, numbers, and underscores as many as possible until the `.`, followed by the last set of characters to end it. You can exchange the `[a-zA-Z]` character set for a explicit set of domains if you'd prefer.

Comment: you need to backslash the first forward slash `\/{2}`

Comment: @i-- Why? Forward slash isn't a character that needs to be escaped.

Comment: Well, I take it back, as I am not that familiar with C#, just errored when I tested in javascript browser console.

Comment: @i-- Fair enough. I'll add it for robustness I suppose. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For your example data you might use a positive lookahead `(?=`) and a positive lookbehind `(?<=)`

[`(?<=")(?:https?:|www\.).+?(?=;?\\")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%22%29%28%3f%3ahttps%3f%3a%7cwww%5c.%29.%2b%3f%28%3f%3d%3b%3f%5c%5c%22%29&i=%22Google%3b%5c%22https%3a%2f%2fgoogle.com%5c%22%22%0d%0a%22Yahoo%3b%5c%22www.yahoo.com%5c%22%22%0d%0a%22https%3a%2f%2fgoogle.com%3b%5c%22https%3a%2f%2fgoogle.com%5c%22%22+)

That would match

- `(?<=")` Positive lookbehind to assert that what is on the left side is a double quote
- `(?:https?:|www\.)` Match either http with an optional s or www.
- `.+?` Match any character one or more times non greedy
- `(?=;?\\")` Positive lookahead which asserts that what follows is an optional `;` followed by`\"`